# I need to add an argument for my preview call. What should I add without stating wether the boolean is true or false?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to add an argument for my preview call. What should I add without stating wether the boolean is true or false?

```
import SwiftUI
struct LiberteIDCreation: View {
    @Binding var LoginSucess: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            return Group {
                if LoginSucess  {
                    ContentView()
                } else {
                    LiberteIDLogin(LoginSucess: self.LoginSucess)
                }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct LiberteIDCreation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
        LiberteIDCreation(LoginSucess: Bool) //what should I add for this? I need to add an agrument for this 
    }
}
```

What can I add to the LiberteLDCreation to make it work? It says it
needs an argument?

Comment: Congrats on your first post! Would be helpful if you provided the actual error message.

Comment: For reference, by convention properties and variables start with a lower case letter, so `loginSuccess` would be the correct name. `LoginSuccess` would be a class, struct, type or enumeration name.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import SwiftUI
struct LiberteIDCreation: View {
    var LoginSucess: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            return Group {
                if LoginSucess  {
                    ContentView()
                } else {

                }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct LiberteIDCreation_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
        LiberteIDCreation(LoginSucess: true)  
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it said Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

Comment: remove `@Binding `

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: you should use  `.constant(false)` in `LiberteIDCreation_Previews`. But here is the other issue, which you need to know. It'll not work correctly in **canvas** in you case (with `if...else` statements), the view will not update. At least in my Xcode version it didn't work. Try examples below to check. :

```swift
struct UsingBindingBool: View {

    @Binding var loginSuccess: Bool
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            return Group {
                if loginSuccess  {
                    Text("success")
                } else {
                    Text("change variable from child").onTapGesture { self.loginSuccess = true }
                }

                Text("other group elements...")
            }
        }

    }
}

struct UsingStateForBinding: View {

    @State private var loginSuccess = false
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            UsingBindingBool(loginSuccess: $loginSuccess)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Text("presenting parent button:").foregroundColor(.red)
            Button(action: {self.loginSuccess = true}) { Text("change to true from parent") }
        }


    }

}

struct UsingBindingBool_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            UsingBindingBool(loginSuccess: .constant(false))
            UsingStateForBinding()
        }

    }
}
```